# Record capybara headless chrome tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails, angularjs, google-chrome, headless, google-chrome-headless

I'm using Headless Chrome to run my Capybara tests for an AngularJS 1.5/Rails 3.2 application. How do I record the tests into a video format? I found this very useful when using the headless gem but now I've changed to headless chrome I cannot use the headless gem.

Here is my setup of headless chrome;

```
Capybara.register_driver(:headless_chrome) do |app|
  caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.chrome(
    chromeOptions: {
                    prefs: {
                            'download.default_directory' => "#{Rails.root}/tmp/downloads",
                            'download.directory_upgrade' => true,
                            'download.prompt_for_download' => false,
                            'plugins.plugins_disabled' => ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]
                           },
                    binary: "/opt/google/chrome-beta/google-chrome",
                    args: %w[headless disable-gpu window-size=1920,1080]
                   }
  )
  Capybara::Selenium::Driver.new(
    app,
    browser: :chrome,
    desired_capabilities: caps
  )
```

Comment: I found a document [here](http://afterdesign.net/2016/02/07/recording-headless-selenium-tests-to-mp4.html) which probably help.